# Get JSON data from Paginated URLs

Tags: angularjs, json, http, cakephp, pagination

I have paginated employees
URL "http://localhost:8765/employees.json?page=1" for page 1, "http://localhost:8765/employees.json?page=2" for page 2 & so on.

I get the data as follows in angularjs:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8765/employees.json?page="+1)
.then(function (response) {
var empData =response.data;
});
```

I want all data from all pages in one variable.

PS: The pagination is done in Backend -> CakePHP, but i need the data in my Frontend -> AngularJS.

Comment: simply do it in a loop. Populate an array of Promises: `promises.push($http.get(url[i]))` and then resolve all of the Promises at the same time with `$q.all(promises)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. @AlekseySolovey